# State variable always gets initial value in header button onPress function react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to submit some fields without any form, only with the state variables. But when I update them their value updates properly but in my header button onPress event they always gets intial values. I don't know anyway to fix this. Here's is my simple code.

```
const [totalExpense, setTotalExpense] = useState('0');
useEffect(() => {
  navigation.setOptions({
    headerRight: () => (
      <IconButton
        name='check'
        bgColor={colors.primary}
        onPress={handleSubmit}
      />
    ),
  });
}, [route, navigation]);

const handleSubmit = () => {
  console.log('total Expense', totalExpense);
};
```

Later I use setTotalExpense() to update the value. But It always get zero in the console when I press on the header right button. It seems that the header button is not able to get the updated value because I get updated value in other places. What am I missing please help me to make this work. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code where you call the `setTotalExpense` method?

Comment: In my return statement like this bellow:
<CustomTextInput value={totalExpense} keyboardType="numeric" onChangeText={(value) => setTotalExpense(value)} />

Comment: As the TextInput Value also changes but it doesn't update in that handleSubmit function only because I think it was referred from header button or something.

Comment: Try to add a `console.log(value)` in the `onChangeText` method of the `CustomTextInput` to see if the event is fired correctly

Comment: Already did that and it updates properly. I am really getting silly why it is behaving like this.

Comment: Try to remove the `value={totalExpense}` attribute, it might cause some overriding

Comment: It's not only with this type of text input, I also tried to get other inputs like date picker. In all cases the values get the initial values when pressing the button. Maybe somehow binding the arrow function in the header button doesn't or not able to track state variables. For your confusion I can assure no mistake was made for the binding values and updating mechanism as this works fine with formik. Only for the header button callback function this is the issue.

Comment: By the way I am using react navigation 5